# How to add constraints about value of two keys of the same object without extracting as generic?

Tags: typescript

```js
const a: Foo<'bar'> = {
  'alpha': {
    a: ['bar'],
    b: { c: 'bar'}
  }
}
```

I want to add compile-time constraint that a[0] must be same as b.c.

```js
type Foo<Bar extends string> = {
  [key: string]: {
    a: [Bar];
    b: { c: Bar };
  }
}
```

The above code adds the compile-time constraint that a[0] must be same as b.c, however the down-side is having to repeat myself when declaring at Foo<'bar'>. Is there a way to do have this constraint without having to define the value explicitly again.

Comment: No, you need to have it generic. But you can write a helper function to infer the type argument for you.  [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/NlMBrm) is how I'd probably do it (assuming you actually want different top-level keys to have different strings associated with them, is that right?)  If that meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?